# Extract filepaths of .MP4 files in subfolders of main folder to textfile

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, terminal, macos-monterey

I am on Mac. I want to use terminal or something to extract the filepaths of the .MP4 files within a folder with multiple levels of subfolders. I have a main folder that has subfolders. Each subfolder has its own subfolders. Eventually in this line, there are .MP4 files. I want a text file with the filepath of each .MP4 file, preferably with commas or semicolons between. Can you help me?

I looked into a few options, but they were either for Windows or not that helpful. The dir command in Windows seemed relevant perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ssmething like can help you (tested on RHEL):

```
printf "%s:" $(dirname $(find . -name "*.MP4") |sort -u)|sed 's/:$//'; echo
```

short explanations

```
find . -name "*.MP4"
```

search for filenames (with paths)

```
dirname $(find . -name "*.MP4") |sort -u
```

get directory name, sort and get unique dirctories

```
printf "%s:" $(dirname $(find . -name "*.MP4") |sort -u)
```

print the directory names and semicolon

```
sed 's/:$//'
```

remove last semicolon

```
echo
```

on the end add new line

Comment: Thank you very much!